Optimal landing point for coastal journey
The original problem is in the form of a story so I am posting it in the original form as it was in the question paper
Cassius, an adventurous sailor, finds himself $2$ km offshore in his sturdy boat, contemplating his journey to a picturesque coastal town nestled $6$ km down the shoreline from the nearest accessible point. The sun hangs low in the sky, casting a golden hue over the tranquil waters as Cassius maps out his strategy.
He knows his capabilities well: rowing steadily at $2$ km/hr or traversing the shoreline by foot at a brisk $5$ km/hr pace. Cassius ponders the optimal landing spot that will minimize his total travel time to reach the bustling town, where he plans to restock supplies and immerse himself in the local culture.
The shoreline curves gently to his left, revealing cliffs and sandy coves that punctuate the rugged coastline. A cool breeze whispers promises of adventure as Cassius calculates the most efficient route. With determination etched on his face, he weighs the options: rowing directly towards the town or landing closer and completing the journey on foot.
Where should Cassius land his boat to ensure the swiftest passage to the coastal town, blending his skillful rowing with a brisk run along the shoreline path?
MY ATTEMPT
The man is positioned $2$ km offshore in the boat, with a coastal town located $6$ km along the shoreline from the nearest accessible point. The rowing speed is $2$ km/hr, and he can run along the shoreline at $5$ km/hr. The objective is to minimize the total travel time to reach the town.
If he were to row directly towards the town, the total distance would be  $2 \text{ km} + 6 \text{ km} = 8 \text{ km}$ . With a rowing speed of 2 km/hr, the time required would be $\frac{8}{2} = 4$  hours.
Alternatively, I  calculated the optimal distance  $x$  to row towards the nearest point on shore, and then run the remaining distance to the town. Using the Pythagorean theorem, I find  $x$  satisfies  $x^2 + 2^2 = (6 - x)^2$ .
Solving this equation,  $x^2 + 4 = 36 - 12x + x^2$ , simplifies to $12x = 32$  and  $x = \frac{8}{3}$ $\approx 2.67 km$.
Next, I calculated the total time for this strategy:

Rowing distance = $2.67$  km, time  = $\frac{2.67}{2} = 1.335$ hours (approximately $1$ hour and $20$ minutes).
Running distance  = $6 - 2.67 = 3.33$  km, time = $\frac{3.33}{5} = 0.666$ hours (approximately $40$ minutes).

Therefore, the total time for the combined strategy is  $1.335 + 0.666 = 2.001$  hours (approximately $2$ hours).
Based on my calculations, landing the boat  $\frac{8}{3}$ km from the nearest point on shore and then running to the town would minimize my total travel time effectively compared to rowing directly to the town but the answer is not matching it is given something else can anyone tell me how can I arrive at the correct answer and where did I went wrong.
